# How to create a temporary table and set it up as the record source for a subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a temporary table using the CreateTableDef method, and set that table as the record source of a subform in my access database when the parent form loads:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim db As Database
Dim tblDef As TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tblDef = db.CreateTableDef("tblMyTable")
tblDef.Fields.Append tblDef.CreateField("Field1", dbText)
tblDef.Fields.Append tblDef.CreateField("Fields", dbText)
tblDef.Fields.Append tblDef.CreateField("Field3", dbText)

db.TableDefs.Append tblDef
db.TableDefs.refresh

Me.sfrm.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblmyTable"
Me.sfrm.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

However, when the execution reaches to: Me.sfrm.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblIHC", it raises the run time error 2467: "the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or does not exist."

Help is appreciated.  Also, do I also need to set the source object property of the subform as well? And to what, if so.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to simple use `currentDB.Execute("CREATE TABLE tblMyTable (Field1 Text, field2 Text, field3 Text);"`

But for the record source have you tried adding a `;` at the end of the Select?

Comment: I plan to eventually use the .Connect and the .SourceTableName properties of TableDef to link it to an external SQL table, and that is why I am trying to make it work with the TableDef object.

Comment: I did try using a ";" at the end of select, and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two subforms?

Should it read:

```
Me!IHCResults_subform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblmyTable"
Me!IHCResults_subform.Form.Requery
```

And, if so, the last line is not needed. The subform will requery when changing the recordsource.

Also have in mind, that when you open the form, first the subform is opened (hidden), then closed, then the parent form is opened, and this opens the subform. So the subform must initially contain a valid recordsource.

Comment: Check the initial recordsource of the subform.

Comment: About your last comment, I moved one step back, and created a form, and tried to do the following:

Me.Recordset = db.TableDefs(tblDef).OpenRecordset

or

Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblMyTable"

None worked!

Comment: The first doesn't work. However, the second will work in the OnOpen event, so if not, something else is going on.